# About Android Layout File

Tags: java, android

I would like to know about custom layout xml files in Android. I came across a code block that tells

```
 <org.superboy.ui.OnlineShop xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/sp_title" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="38dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/shop_background"
    >
```

There is a file called `OnlineShop.java` in the `src/org/superboy/ui`
I did not understand about creating such layouts other than default layout files that we create for activities. Any help pointing to such layouts or advice.

Comment: Which error you get when you run the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can create anything such as TextViews etc. through a class and extend TextView, and then in your XML layout just add an item like above. Here is an example of a [ResizeableTextView](http://pastebin.com/wLtFGxtb) I made and an [XML](http://pastebin.com/U2m1Z0eT) layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will see that the `OnlineShop.java` class will extend something like the following :

- `ViewGroup`
- `View`
- `LinearLayout`
- `RelativeLayout` ect.

These all are objects that can be used in your xml file as a `View`. We call them custom `Views`.

You create custom `Views` when you have a specification in your app that cannot be handled by the standard `View` controls that Android provided (which will not be often because the default `View` controls are very versatile).

You can go read up on it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that your OnlineShop.java file resides in which package,
if your java file resides in `your.project.package` then you must change your layout file as

```
<your.project.package.OnlineShop xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sp_title" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="38dip"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/shop_background"
>
```

Now compiler will refer your onlineShop.java file from your packages.

**general information**

when we place any XML code in our layout file let suppose bellow code

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

it looks our layout file from android.jar package which are included automatically in eclipse while making a new android project.

So if you make any custom layout then you have to create your own java class extending from any `view or viewgroup` in your own package and it should be declared in your XML file mentioning your package see my above code

Hope this helps :)